# Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2019 - Temp tables not visible but SQL says they already exist

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, temp-tables, sql-server-2019

I recently upgraded my SQL Server and Visual Studio IDE to the 2019 versions. Have run into some new behaviors and can't find a solution to my problem. I was creating a stored proc in VS that uses local temp tables and hit an error that stopped the debugger. I was expecting VS to auto-close and delete the temp tables so that once the bug was fixed, I could continue working. Apparently, this didn't happen as once I restarted the SQL debugger it complained that the temp tables already existed. I went looking in the tempdb database for them, they're not there, but I continue getting this message.

I've done the usual stuff, wrote a query to list the temp tables by name, nothing shows up. Searched by ObjectID and nothing. Closed my connection and exited VS, restart and the problem persists. I even rebooted SQL Server thinking some maint tasks might cleanup the temp tables. No luck.

Since they were local temp tables with names like #table1 #table2 and I was logged into my domain with an Admin account, I changed the query to use global temp tables with names like ##table1, ##table2. Restarted the SP again and still, it complains the tables exist. So I logged in to SQL server as admin and went looking again in the tempdb, there's nothing there except what SQL server uses for its own work.

Thinking I could solve this problem by simply using altogether different names for my temp tables, I changed my SP, restarted the debugger and low and behold, it tells me these temp tables, now with different names on a 1st-time use, already exist.

Now I'm feeling a little paranoid like my server knows what I'm thinking and is screwing with me for giggles and grins. I'm out of ideas and could use a helping hand. WTF is going on that new table names on first use would come back as already existing?

The code looks like this for each of the 3 temp tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #MsgFailureLogs
(
    [SourceLogId] [int] NULL,
    [SmtpConversationId] [int] NULL,
    [SmtpExLogId] [int] NULL,
    [SmtpDebugId] [int] NULL,
    [HostIp] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [HostName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [HostDomain] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Socket] [int] NULL,
    [ClientIp] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [ResponseCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Explanation] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [MsgDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LogEntryType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MsgID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [LineNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Temporary tables persist for the duration of the scope that created them or they are dropped; it appears you never disconnected the session you created them in, and as you are using the same session they still exist in the context of that scope. Disconnecting and reconnecting would be but one method to get them to drop.

Comment: Also, don't swear in your posts, even if it is an acronym.

Comment: If you rebooted your server but encountering the same issue you must be creating them somewhere already? TempDB does not survive a reboot, it's create fresh on startup.

Comment: Sorry about the acronym.

Comment: I ran these queries to get the names of temp tables in the tempdb. none of them returned a tabled name that is used in my adhoc query. 
SELECT name 
FROM tempdb.sys.objects
WHERE type = 'U';

SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'Base Table';

USE tempdb;
EXEC sp_tables '#%';

I've' now rebooted both SQL server and my workstation twice, plus changed the table names before running any queries anywhere. and yet it says they still exist. Both the server and WS are VM's I'll try rebooting the host systems as well.

Comment: Rebooted the host platforms the VM's were running on.. Opened the query in VS, changed the table names, then ran the syntax checker only. It reports these new table names, which haven't yet been executed, as already existing. How can this be???

Comment: What happens if you just use `create table if not exists`

Comment: I would add DROP TABLE <#YourTempTableName> command at the end of the procedure. Also at the beginning of the proc I would add DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <#YourTempTableName>

Comment: You are using both `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT INTO` for the same table, you cannot do this. Please supply your full stored procedure. This is absolutely nothing to do with closing or reopening connections or dropping tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem but can't explain why at the moment. I commented out the create temp table syntax on 2 of the larger temp tables, the 3rd has only 1 field and int. Ran the sql query without these predefined table structures and it didn't complain about temp tables already exists. Funny thing is, that 3rd table with a single int field, is predefined in code. All tables use either a SELECT INTO or an INSERT INTO. Why the interpreter doesn't complain about 1 table but does on the others, is a mystery for now. I've been working with LINQ forever, so I'm guessing this is new behavior for SQL 2019 or VS 2019. That or  I've simply forgotten such details over the years. Thanks for the feedback.